# Recommended Sound Libraries - WW2 Vehicles and Weapons

Tags: sfx, sound-libraries, sound-effects, post-production

Hi all!  I'm about to enter production for a WW2 era short, but I'm somewhat limited by both the budget and my location (Australia) as far as recording original audio for vehicles and weaponry for post production (which I will also be doing).

I was wondering if anybody can recommend some SFX libraries for purchase that will allow me to maintain some level of period authenticity in my sound design?

Thanks!

Comment: Cant you access vehicles from the shoot?

Comment: @Tim As far as I know there won't be any; the film takes place inside a concentration camp, following the relationship between an inmate and a guard, with a majority interior scenes.  It's a Master's degree film, with most of the limited budget going towards costumes and firearms/armourer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, a fellow Australian sound editor. First up Rabbit Ears Audio have a bunch of tank libraries. You can buy them separately or in a bundle here: http://rabbitearsaudio.com/rea005-military-vehicles/

Are you in Victoria per chance? I was actually out at a track that has WW2 era Centurion tank. Though the Rabbit Ears library doesn't any recording of the Centurion tank, they do have other WW2 era tanks - including ones that sound pretty similar to the Centurion. However, I unfortunately got to the track too late to record the Centurion. Their website is http://melbourne4x4.com.au/?page_id=38 if you'd like to swing by and record it yourself. Or if you're not in Victoria, maybe we could come to some kind of arrangement?

For planes, the Sound Librarian has a couple of period/WW2 planes in their collection: http://www.prosoundeffects.com/the-aviation-collection.html

And here's the Boom Library historical firearms library mentioned before: http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/products/historical-firearms

And the Blastwave warfare packs that were also mentioned : http://www.blastwavefx.com/Warfare/c59/index.html

Some of these packs are pretty expensive though - but they do appear to be pretty comprehensive. Lastly, for reference material, Youtube is a good starting point for finding videos of period vehicles/weapons. After hearing what they sound like there, you may even find you can design convincing effects using your existing sound library. Good luck!

Comment: @SqueakyFish Thank you! These are some awesome resources.
I'm located in Brisbane, and a Victoria trip is probably not in the budget. That 4x4 link is awesome though, I'll be checking whether there's anything similar up this way!

Comment: No worries. By the way, is some of the film shot in Victoria? If so, I think a couple of my friends are working in the costume department - small world. :D

Answer (score 1):

I think Blastwave FX has a period combat and also Boom Library.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Nokes of Sounddogs.com recorded extensive coverage of an M5A1 Stuart tank.

Highly recommended.

http://www.sounddogs.com/extendedsearch.asp?Keyword=nokes%20tanks